# Postgresql not truncating overlength strings

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, create-table, postgresql-9.3

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-character.html), strings longer than that specified by character varying or VARCHAR should be truncated:

> If one explicitly casts a value to character varying(n) or character(n), then an over-length value will be truncated to n characters without raising an error. (This too is required by the SQL standard.)

but I can not get it to work. Now the documentation does say one has to "explicitly" cast a value to character varying so maybe I am missing that. Below is a simple test table:

```
create table test1(
tval character varying(20));
```

where the following fails with ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(20)

```
insert into test1 values 
('this is a super long string that we want to see if it is really truncated');
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: What documentation says that long strings will be automatically truncated? Can you quote the relevant documentation or provide a link? MySQL does that sort of thing (depending on how it is configured), PostgreSQL is more sensible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This won't truncate, because it's just an assignment:

```
create table test1(tval character varying(20));

insert into test1 values ('this is a super long string that we want to see if it is really truncated');
```

but this will, because it's an *explicit cast*:

```
insert into test1 values (CAST('this is a super long string that we want to see if it is really truncated' AS varchar(20)));
```

To get truncation behaviour you must use an explicit cast, and frankly I wish the SQL standard didn't specify that.

The better way to handle this is to be explicit about what you want:

```
insert into test1 values (left('this is a super long string that we want to see if it is really truncated', 20));
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps as I was having to truncate prior to the insert

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, not to specify the n when creating the column:
If you desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use text or character varying without a length specifier, rather than making up an arbitrary length limit.)